# "with labels" in splot causes gnuplot crash

Tags: gnuplot, label

Well, not really crash, but a kind of infinite loop: gnuplot doesn't react.
I' m trying to have a contour plot from a datafile, with labels on each contour line. Here's my gnuplot code:

```
set key at screen 1, 0.9, 0 right top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitle nobox
set view map
unset surface
set isosamples 50, 50
set contour base
set cntrparam bspline
set cntrparam order 8
set cntrparam levels discrete -25,-50,-100,-150,-300,-500
set style data lines
set title "plot" 
set xlabel "Temps (ns)" 
set xrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set ylabel "T_e" 
set yrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
splot "Hydro-fct-temps.csv" u 1:3:6 lw 2
```

This code works fine, but if I replace the splot line with (as I've seen in http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/contours.html):

```
splot "Hydro-fct-temps.csv" u 1:3:6 lw 2, "Hydro-fct-temps.csv" u 1:3:6 with labels boxed
```

then gnuplot doesn't plot anything, and I only can get the prompt with a ctrl-c. The data file is something like :

```
#Time [ns]      N_e [1/cc]      T_e [eV]        Z               Rho [gr/cc] Pos [um]        
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    4.100000e+01    8.500000e+00    0.000000e+00    
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    4.100000e+01    8.500000e+00    4.579648e-03    
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    4.100000e+01    8.500000e+00    9.191354e-03    
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    4.100000e+01    8.500000e+00    1.383534e-02
```

Any idea to help me? Thanks!

Edit: I'm on Mac OS 10.11.4, using Gnuplot 5.0.3, aqua terminal

Comment: Which os? Which terminal? Which gnuplot version? could you upload the data somewhere (how big is it?)?

Comment: @bibi I've edited my question to be more specific. The datafile is > 24 Mb, and I cannot upload it as it is the result of a non-public simulation code.

Comment: try to use `x11` terminal, since data is quite big it might be possible that it's difficult to render for the aqua terminal.  Does the computer hangs or it still uses cpu/memory when it becomes idle?

Comment: The computer doesn't hang, it's just gnuplot (it takes 99% of the processor). The X11 terminal doesn't change anything.

Comment: so, my guess is the data is too big

Comment: You are probably right, but why the problem appears only when I try to put labels? The line `splot "Hydro-fct-temps.csv" u 1:3:6 lw 2` works fine, but the line `splot "Hydro-fct-temps.csv" u 1:3:6 lw 2, "Hydro-fct-temps.csv" u 1:3:6 with labels boxed` doesn't.

Comment: You probably need to filter-out some data using `every` to make things easier for gnuplot. You probably don't need all the data to place just some label

Comment: If @bibi is right and your data file is too large, the reason that it only fails when you add labels is because you are adding twice as much information to the graph.  Doing `splot datafile` will add one item for every line in the data file.  Doing `slot datafile, splot datafile w labels` needs to add those AND add another full series of data (the labels) making twice as much information for the terminal to have to keep track of.  Try the suggestion that @bibi gave you and see if that works. Also try one of the non-interactive terminals (png for example) to see if the terminal's a problem.